# Alias for directory using a symbol

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, alias

I'm looking to set up an alias for my work directory, which can change as I change context, and I was trying to find something that was short enough to stand in as a replacement for `~`.  I'd be tickled pink if it's possible to have a one character name for the alias. Like `cd %` or something? Assigning an alias to `%` doesn't seem to work though.

I've tried looking for requirements for variable names, but I couldn't find any. I don't know if this is a shell built-in, I can't have been the first person to want to do this.

I'm using zsh, but I tagged bash in case it's something possible in both shells.

Comment: Does the alias work for a single letter like `x`? or what about a number `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zsh` provides several facilities to get what you want, but the closest I could come up with is:

```
alias -g %=/path/to/whereever
```

Which will substitute that path for `%` anywhere inside a command. You could also try:

```
alias '%'='cd /path/to/whereever'
```

Now `%` is a command to change directly to that directory. There is also

```
hash -d work=/path/to/whereever
```

Which would let you use `~work` to refer to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to zsh, but for bash, aliases are only used for commands not arguments.

You probably want to write a function:

```
cdw () {
    case $(pwd) in 
        */some/dir)       cd ../work ;;
        */some/other/dir) cd ~/tmp ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: why `$(pwd)` and not `$PWD`?

Comment: because I use both of them so rarely I forget about the variable.